# Change the name of Bibliography

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies

I am using the `\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}` to import my Bibliography. However, I would like to change the name, both in the ToC and the header, I have tried to use commands such as `\renewcommand{\bibname}{header}` and `\renewcommand{\refname}{header}` but without success. I'm using babel with English if that matters.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: This should be a duplicate; the answer is to do `\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\bibname}{header}\renewcommand{\refname}{header}}`

Answer (score 0):

Just use in your preamble:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\def\bibname{header}}
```

It should do the trick.